# How to upgrade SQLite deferred Transaction to RESERVED

Tags: sqlite, transactions

I'm inserting data to a database where each "batch" must have a new unique id for the batch itself. I could add a batch table and use it's AUTOINCREMENT id, but I don't really need it for anything else, so it seems excessive.

I'm currently doing a SELECT MAX(batchid) + 1 FROM items and then using it for inserts, this is of course prone to race-conditions (2 new batches simultaneously can get conflicting ids)

Using an IMMEDIATE transaction is impractical. Is it possible to force an upgrade of a DEFERRED transaction to EXCLUSIVE before doing the select?

Some ideas;

- Can I do some No-op cheap update?
- Some explicit instruction to now go exclusive?
- `INSERT INTO items (batchid, value) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(batchid)+1 FROM items), "monkey"), ((SELECT MAX(batchid)+1 FROM items), "banana")`, the idea being that the select is now explicitly part of the update?

Answer (score 1):

It would indeed be possible to put the batch ID lookup into a subquery, but that would be a lot of duplication.

The easiest way is to do something to write to the database, such as [PRAGMA user_version = x](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version).